# Wave-equation on a horn

Tags: partial-differential-equations, inner-products, wave-equation, eigenfunctions

Consider a conical horn, generated by the curve $y=Kx$ ($0<x<L$) rotating about the x-axis. The intersection surface of the horn is $a(x)=\pi K^2x^2$.

The related wave-equation is

\begin{equation}
u_{tt}+c^2\mathcal{A}u=0
\end{equation}

and where the identity:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg(x^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg)=\frac{1}{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}(xu)
\end{equation}

The horn is finite, hence $u$ is bounded and $u_x(L,t)=0$.

The function $u$ is actually $u=\frac{p-p_0}{p_0}$ where  $p$ is the pressure from the sound waves and $p_0$ is the equilibrium pressure.

How do I find a scalar product  with respect to which eigenfunctions to A with the given B.C. which are pairwise orthogonal?

**My attempt:**

Since the conditions are clearly Neumann conditions, I have the ansatz: $u(x,t)=u(t)\cos\frac{n\pi}{L}x$. So a scalar product would be

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n(t)\cos\frac{n\pi}{L}x$

But is this really so simple?

Then I should find the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues for the operator $\mathcal{A}$ under the given conditions.

**My attempt**

Here i simply solved the stationary problem:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A}u=0\\
-\frac{1}{\pi K^2 x^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(\pi K^2 xu)=0\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\pi K^2 xu)=C\\
(\pi K^2 xu)=Cx+D\\
u(x)=\frac{Cx+D}{\pi K^2 x}, \ \ \ \ \ \  I.C.: u(L)=0: \\
u(x)=-\frac{\frac{D}{L}x+D}{\pi K^2 x} 
\end{equation}

But this is giving only a partially revealed eigenfunction for the operator $\mathcal{A}u$.

Then , how do I find the eigenfrequencies, when I clearly cannot solve this wave equation without getting the nonsolvable PDE from inserting the ansatz in the original wave equation:

\begin{equation}
u_{tt}+\bigg[\frac{c^2}{x}-\frac{c^2n}{K^2xL}\cot\frac{n\pi}{L}x\bigg]u(t)=0
\end{equation}

Any hints appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Is the wave equation to be solved in the *volume* bounded by a cone or on the *surface* of a cone? Or something else? What is $a(x)$? (I've not heard the term intersection surface before). This looks to be either a 2d or a 3d problem, so you should have at least one more co-ordinate :)

Comment: So a cone with a circular 'lid', yes? On which surface do you want to solve the wave equation? The surface of the cone, or the lid? And whichever surface you it is, they'll be two spatial co-ordinates on it, say $x,z$ if it's the cone surface. Do I misunderstand you?

Comment: Is that surface a disk?

Comment: The question seems interesting and I'd like to help but I simply don't understand the problem. Can you either: explicitly state the region, in co-ordinates, on which you want to solve the wave equation and the associated boundary conditions, or, provide a diagram showing this region?

Comment: Sure, since $\pi Kx^2$, it looks like a $\pi r^2$ formula. However, the horn is directed horizontally   along the x-axis, so the radius should have been $y$. Therefore, your question is a good question, as the surface defined by $a(x)$ is actually not a surface, but a line along the inner surface. It seems the wave propagation is therefore meant to be calculated along a curve, rather than a surface. But the exercise says "intersection surface". Maybe it is a bad explanation of what $a(x)$ really is. So we want to calculate the wave propagation along a one dimensional curve, $a(x)$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $x^2$ instead of $x$ inside the parenthesis of the second displayed equation? As written, the units don't work out.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have rewritten that respective identity. But it still left me oblivious about the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a complete solution will help to show the general methods.

Let us study the wave equation on the surface of the cone:

$$\tag{1}
\nabla^2u(r,\phi,t)=\partial_{tt}u(r,\phi,t) \qquad, \quad0\leq r\leq R,\quad 0\leq\phi\leq 2\pi,\quad t\geq 0 
$$

Where $r$ and $\phi$ are the *spherical* radial and azimuthal co-ordinates, and $\theta=\alpha$ a constant (the internal half-angle of the cone, your constant $L=R \cos(\alpha)$). I've set $c=1$ for my convenience. My cone is aligned with the $z$ not $x$ axis. I'll choose the initial and boundary conditions to be

$$\tag{2}
u(r,\phi,0)=f(r) \qquad,\quad \partial_t u(r,\phi,0)=0,\quad \partial_ru(R,\phi,t)=0
$$

That is: an initial axisymmetric displacement $f$, no initial velocity, and a Neumann condition at the circular opening of the cone. At $r=0$ we must have $\partial_r u=0$ to ensure that $u$ is differentiable. Restricting the Laplacian in (1) to the cone surface yields

$$\tag{3}
\nabla^2u=\frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r(r^2\partial_r u)+\frac{1}{\sin(\alpha)r^2}\partial_{\phi \phi}u 
$$

For axisymmetric solutions the second term on the RHS of (3) vanishes, and separation of varaiables $u(r,t)=S(r)T(t)$ yields

$$\tag{4}
\frac{1}{r^2 S}\partial_r(r^2\partial_r S)=\frac{T''}{T}:=-k^2
$$

The eigenvalue problem for $S(r)$ is

$$\tag{5}
\partial_r(r^2\partial_r S)=-r^2 k^2 S
$$

This is a [Sturm-Liouville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) problem with eigenvalues $k^2$, and weight function $w(r)=r^2$. Equation (5) may be solved directly using the transformation $v(r)=rS(r)$. The solutions are

$$\tag{6}
S(r)=\frac{1}{r}\left[A\sin(kr)+B\cos(kr) \right]
$$

Using $S'(0)=0$ sets $B=0$ and $S'(R)=0$ sets the allowed values of $k$ to be solutions to the transcendental equation

$$\tag{7}
kR=\tan(kR)
$$

Call the nonzero roots of (7) $k_n$ with $n=1,2,3,\dots$. Call the eigenfunctions of (5) $S_n(r)$. They will be orthogonal with respect to weight $w(r)$ and the following inner product

$$\tag{8}
\int\limits_0^R dr \ w(r)S_n(r)S_m(r)=\delta_{nm}
$$

The eigenvalues are really $k_n^2$ so both $k_n$ and $-k_n$ are to be identified with the same eigenfunction. The normalized eigenfunctions are

$$\tag{9}
S_n(r)=\frac{1}{\sin(k_nR)}\sqrt{\frac{2}{R }}\frac{\sin(k_n r)}{r} \qquad,\quad n=1,2,3,\dots \\
S_0(r)=\sqrt{\frac{3}{R^3}}=\text{constant}
$$

Note we deal with the $k=0$ eigenfunction separately. The initial condition $f(r)$ may be expanded in the $S_n$ basis by setting $f=c_0 S_0+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty c_n S_n$ and applying (8)

$$\tag{10}
\int\limits_0^R dr \ r^2 S_n(r) f(r)=c_n \qquad,\quad n=1,2,3,\dots \\
c_0=S_0\int\limits_0^R dr \ r^2 f(r)
$$

The $T(t)$ eigenfunctions may be found from (4). The ones with $T'(0)=0$ are

$$\tag{11}
T_n(t)=\cos(k_n t)
$$

The $k=0$ eigenfunction has no time dependance either: it is a constant. Using (9), (10), (11) and the definition of $k_n$ completes the solution:

$$\tag{12}
u(r,t)=c_0 S_0+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty c_n S_n(r) \cos(k_n t)
$$

If you want to study non-asixymmetric problems, ie. $f=f(r,\phi)$, then you simply go back to (3) and keep the term involving $\partial_\phi$. You will then have *two* separation constants in (4)- but the overall method remains the same. The $\phi$ part of the eigenfunctions will be $e^{im\phi}$ for integer $m$.

Comment: Thanks Sal, I will study this carefully in the week!

Comment: Great, no problem!